# Can 2D matrix be rotated with 90° in a better time complexity than O(n^2)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Here is an example input/output of a matrix rotation:

```
Input: [[1,2,3,],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
Output: [[7,4,1], [8,5,2], [9,6,3]]
```

I understand that a rotation can be performed with O(n^2) time complexity.

Is there a quicker solution possible? What would it be?

Comment: What is `n` here ? The dimension of the matrix ? Or the number of elements ?

Comment: If n is the width of the matrix, then no, it cannot be quicker, as O(n²) values need to move.

Comment: It is *not* o(n²), but O(n²).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a matrix of width/height *n* cannot be rotated with a better time complexity than *O(n²)*. This is because there are *O(n²)* values that need to be moved.

However, there is a way that you could get around this:

You could decide to not really *perform* the rotation, but just make *note* of the rotation, and translate any subsequent access to the matrix accordingly. If you do it like that, then a matrix rotation has *O(1)* time complexity.

Here is a simple demo of that idea in JavaScript. The class `Matrix` should be extended with all methods you want to support (like `set`, `invert`, `determinant`, ...etc), where each will have to take into account this particularity. But that wouldn't affect their own time complexities.

```js
class Matrix {
    constructor(rows) {
        // Take a copy of the 2d-array passed as argument
        this.rows = [];
        for (let row of rows) {
            this.rows.push(Array.from(row));
        }
        this.rotation = 0;
        this.n = rows.length;
    }
    rotate90() {
        this.rotation = (this.rotation + 1) % 4;
    }
    get(rowIdx, colIdx) {
        switch (this.rotation) {
        case 0: return this.rows[rowIdx][colIdx];
        case 1: return this.rows[this.n-1-colIdx][rowIdx];
        case 2: return this.rows[this.n-1-rowIdx][this.n-1-colIdx];
        case 3: return this.rows[colIdx][this.n-1-rowIdx];
        }
    }
    toString() {
        let txt = "";
        for (let rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < this.n; rowIdx++) {
            txt += "\n";
            for (let colIdx = 0; colIdx < this.n; colIdx++) {
                txt += " " + this.get(rowIdx, colIdx);
            }
        }
        return txt.slice(1);
    }
}


// Demo
let m = new Matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]);

console.log(m.toString());

for (let rot = 1; rot <= 4; rot++) {
    m.rotate90();
    console.log(m.toString());
}
```

Comment: How do you know what the rotated indicies will be? That's always difficult for me to get right.

Comment: @0x499602D2, just draw it on a piece of paper. At each rotation the two coordinates switch roles, and one of them inverts (counting from the opposite side).